# Multiple Regression: Only interpret unstandardized coefficients when all variables have the same scale (0-10)?

Tags: multiple-regression

I am developing a multiple regression model using three predictor and one outcome variable.
All variables use the same scale (0-10).
Therefore it should suffice to look at the unstandardized coeffients for interpretation, shouldn't it? Are the coeffecients comparable as to "size" of their effect?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always fine to look at unstandardized coefficients.  I don't typically use standardized coefficients for much.  Comparing the values of different coefficients to each other and interpreting that as a measure of 'importance' (which is what I think you're getting at) is a dicey affair.  To do so, you need to assume that the units of the different variables are commensurate (if X1 is meters and X2 is seconds, how many meters equals 1 second?), which is usually not reasonable.  The fact that your variables are all scaled 0-10 makes this *look* less suspicious, but doesn't necessarily make it better in actuality.

A different issue is whether your outcome variable is also 0-10.  It sounds like it is.  If so, standard (i.e., OLS) multiple regression may not be valid.  If the Y data don't approach the bounds and the residuals look normal enough, you should be fine, but otherwise you may want to do ordinal logistic regression.